# Conditional Where clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

suppose i am showing data in grid and i have many textboxes for filter the data.
textbox for employee id. if employee id textbox is empty then no where clause will be added but if it is not empty then where clause will be added for that. the same way we can filter data if salary textbox has value or employee name textbox has value.

i try to compose a conditional LINQ query but got error. here is mine

```
var sName="";

var r = from t in TblFamilies
where 1 == 1
if(sName!="")
{
  && t.Name="Keith";
};

select new
{
    t.ID,
    t.ParentID,
    t.Name,
    t.CurDate
};

r.Dump();
```

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: Dynamic queries is that what you want.

Comment: i was testing linq in linq pad.

Comment: You can easily chain multiple `.Where()` functions after a query. You don't need to create a "conditional where". Even in SQL, a "conditional where" is bad practice because it will result in inefficient execution plans

Comment: Are you sure that you want to search Keith if the user enters Jim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

First select the data:-

```
var r = from t in TblFamilie
select new
{
    t.ID,
    t.ParentID,
    t.Name,
    t.CurDate
};
```

Then you can filter based on condition:-

```
   if (sName!="")
        r = r.Where(x => x.Name == sName);
```

Comment: The `1==1` isn't needed

Comment: @RahulSingh : thanks. it worked. the way u add the filter linq will generate AND keyword instead of OR. so how could i make it dynamic. suppose i will say what operator linq will use to generate sql like `And , OR`

Comment: @Mou - You can use `||` operator in the Where clause itself : - `r.Where(x => x.Name == sName || x.Name = "Test")' for example.

Comment: see my sql `where Name='Keith' OR ID=2`. i do not want to use always AND operator like  `Name='Keith' AND ID=2`

Comment: @Mou - That's what I am saying, you can write: `if (id > 0) {
        r = r.Where(x => x.Name == "Keith" || x.ID == 2); }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mix `And` operator and `Or` operator together, check `PredicateBuilder` out here: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

You can simply write like:

```
// begin with true if you start with And operator.
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TblFamilie>();
predicate = predicate.And(t => t.CureDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
// you can mix with Or operator too.
predicate = predicate.Or(t => t.Name.Contains("blah"));

var results = context.TblFamilie
.Where(predicate)
.Select(new
{
  // your projection here...
});


// begin with false if you start with Or operator.
var predicate2 = PredicateBuilder.False<TblFamilie>();
predicate2 = predicate2.Or(t => t.CureDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
// you can mix with And operator too.
predicate2 = predicate2.And(t => t.Name.Contains("blah"));

var results = context.TblFamilie
.Where(predicate)
.Select(new
{
  // your projection here...
});


// even nesting is possible
var inner = PredicateBuilder.False<TblFamilie>();
inner = inner.Or (p => p.Name.Contains("foo"));
inner = inner.Or (p => p.Name.Contains("bar"));

var outer = PredicateBuilder.True<TblFamilie>();
outer = outer.And (p => p.CureDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-3));
outer = outer.And (p => p.CureDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
outer = outer.And (inner);

var results = context.TblFamilie
.Where(outer)
.Select(new
{
  // your projection here...
});
```

**Updated**

Okay, lets assume you have a `Family` class, and you get 'Families' from some where. You can use `PredicateBuilder` like this:

```
// you have 4 families from DB, API or anywhere.
var failies = new List<Family>
{
    new Family { Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "foo", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 1, 1) },
    new Family { Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "bar", Birthday = new DateTime(1982, 1, 1) },
    new Family { Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "foobar", Birthday = new DateTime(1993, 1, 1) },
    new Family { Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "fake", Birthday = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) },
};

// make predicate!
// if a family's Birthday is before than 1980 'or' Name contains "ke".
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Family>();
predicate = predicate.And(o => o.Birthday < new DateTime(1980, 1, 1));
predicate = predicate.Or(o => o.Name.Contains("ke"));

// you should make IQueryable in order to use PredicateBuilder.
var result = failies.AsQueryable()
    .Where(predicate)
    .Select(o => new
    {
        o.Id, o.Name, o.Birthday    // only project what you want.
    })
    .ToList();

// now, result should contains "foo" and "fake".
foreach (var family in result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + family.Name);
}
```

**Updated2**

You can copy & paste to LinqPad in order to test how it works. Before you run this in the LinqPad,

- Download `LinqKit.dll` from above link.
- Make sure press 'F4' > Add > Browse > select LinqKit.dll > Add `LinqKit` namespace in the 'Additional Namespace Imports' tab.
- In the Query panel, choose Language to 'C# Statement(s)'

paste this and run.

```
// you have 4 strings from DB, API or anywhere.
var strings = new List<string>
{
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "foobar",
    "fake"
};


// make predicate!
// if a string contains "oo" or "ke"
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<string>();
predicate = predicate.And(o => o.Contains("oo"));
predicate = predicate.Or(o => o.Contains("ke"));

// you should make IQueryable in order to use PredicateBuilder.
var result = strings.AsQueryable()
    .Where(predicate)
    .ToList();

// now, result should contains "foo", "foobar" and "fake".
foreach (var stringResult in result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + stringResult);
}
```

Comment: for PredicateBuilder do i need to add any assembly or any class which does not come with dotnet.

Comment: Yes, visit the site that I posted, you can grab the source code in the article. It's only a class with few lines of code. I don't think there's any restrictions bothers you.

Comment: i add linqkit in LINQPad and try to execute a query u gave but got error `'LINQPad.User.TypedDataContext.TblFamilies' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'`

Comment: Above code is only a sample, not exact. In the `PredicateBuilder.True<TblFamilie>`, you should change `TblFamile` to its actual 'Type'. And I assumed you're using sort of ORM such as EntityFramework or something. If you're not, Call `.AsQueryable()` after the source `IEnumerable` instance. PredicateBuilder only works with `IQueryable`.

Comment: i am not using EF and not being able to understand how to use predicate builder again my table TblFamilies in LINQ pad which would run properly. can u plzz construct the statement with PredicateBuilder which would run successfully.

Comment: i guess still i could not run your code in LINQPad. suggest me how to run predicate related code in LINQPad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74344/discussion-between-gongdo-gong-and-mou).

Comment: thanks now i paste your code and could run it but could not see what sql linqpad generate. when i click on sql icon then nothing shown. so just do not understand AND or OR which operator has been used. can u suggest something. thanks for your help.

Comment: According the StackOverflow policy, I'll discuss further only in chat. Please click the chat link for further discussion. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74344/discussion-between-gongdo-gong-and-mou